# If for some sets $A, B$ we have their symmetric difference $(A-B) \cup (B-A) =B$. Then does that imply $A=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If for some sets $A, B$ we have their symmetric difference $(A-B) \cup (B-A) =B$. Then does that imply $A=\emptyset$

My Attempt

If $x\in B$ then

$$ x \in (A-B) \cup (B-A) $$

Then

$$x \in (A-B) $$ or $$ x\in (B-A) $$

Note that $x \in (A-B)$ is impossible since $x\in B$

We must have $$ x\in (B-A) $$ such implies that $ x \not \in A$ hence $A \cap B=\emptyset$  (Hope I am correct upto this.)

If I further show $ A \cup B=B$ then I can conclude that $A= \emptyset$, this solution is one of my classmates. But can there be a better proof?

But can someone help me with an elementary proof.

Comment: @Kaynex the property you mention is exactly the property needing to be proven here.  You can't use a result to prove itself, that is circular reasoning.

Comment: As for your attempt at a proof @ Rakesh, it is fine.  You showed that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ well, but rather than showing $A=\emptyset$ via showing $A\cup B=B$., I would instead approach by contrapositive/contradiction.  Supposing that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ *and* $A$ is nonempty, then there should be some element $a\in A-B$, but then that would have meant ______...  (*also, as a typesetting note, `\emptyset` is more common than `\phi`*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\in A$ then

(i). If $\;a\in B$ then  $a\in A\cap B=A\cap (A\Delta B)=A$ \ $B$  so $a\not \in B, $   a contradiction.

(ii). If $\; a\not \in B$ then   $a\in A$ \ $ B \subset A\Delta B=B$   so $ a\in B, $ a contradiction.

So no $a$ belongs to $A.$

Comment: For a direct proof:  Since $A=(A$  \ $B ) \cup (A\cap B),$ show first that $A\cap B=A$  \  $B$ and show second that $A \backslash B =\phi.$  First, $A\cap B=A \cap (A\Delta B)=A$  \ $ B.$  Second,  $A$  \ $ B=   (A\backslash B)\cap (A\Delta B)=(A \backslash  B)\cap B=\phi.$